# Automatically activating Python venv when using PowerShell in PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, python-venv

When using `cmd.exe` as the terminal application in PyCharm, the Python venv for the project gets automatically activated, so, I don't need to run `venv\Scripts\activate`. But when using PowerShell this doesn't happen. Is it possible to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

This is the option that has to be ticked to activate the Python virtual environment:

[image]

which is ticked by default and was ticket in my case. The reason why it wasn't working (and failing silently) was because I move the parent directory to a different location on my hard drive and that seemed to break the venv. Deleting it and re-creating it fixed the problem.

Comment: This is currently an open ticket about this, see [youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22469](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22469)